# jQuery Mobile Slider outputting wrong code

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider, range

I have a page with a slider that is connected to a deepzoomable image. That slider uses the jQuery slider plugin and now I would like to make that slider mobile friendly. 
I started with just adding a static mobile slider. I added the jQuery mobile css and js and inserted the `input[type="range"]` as such:

```html
<input type="range" id="zoomRange" value="25" min="0" max="100" />
```

I did not add a label since I've found it is not absolutely necessary.
And the outputted code in the DOM is as follows:

```html
<input type="number" data-type="range" max="100" min="0" value="25" id="zoomRange"
       class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-shadow-inset">
<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-link" style="left: 0%;"></a>
```

Is anyone familiar with what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

From the jQueryMobile docs

> The framework will find all input elements with a type="range" and
>   automatically enhance them into a slider with an accompanying input

So what you see is perfectly normal.I assume you want to get away with that spinner and just have the slider alone.You can do it in two ways.

1) Use `data-role="none"` with the `input` type.This will tell the jQuery Mobile framework not to enhance the input type and it will look like a plain html slider.

2) Hide the spinner by manipulating the CSS.

I think point no. 2 will do the trick for you.

Here is a sample code that illustrates what I am talking.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=
  "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=
  "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js">
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
       #slider-2{
         display:none;
         }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page1</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="slider-0">jQueryMobile Default</label> <input type="range" name=
        "slider" id="slider-0" value="25" min="0" max="100">
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="slider-1">data-role='none'</label> <input type="range" name="slider"
        id="slider-1" value="25" min="0" max="100" data-role="none">
      </div>

      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="slider-2">Spinner hidden</label> <input type="range" name="slider"
        id="slider-2" value="25" min="0" max="100">
      </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/2SXV6/

Let me know if that help